# Sublime Merge - How to emulate git log -p <folder>

Tags: git, sublimemerge

I want to get the logs of a specific folder in the repo.
How do I do that in Sublime Merge?

For example, with this tree:

```
root
├── services
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── protobuf
└── workers
    ├── asyncprocess
    │   ├── pom.xml
    ├── demux
    │   └── pom.xml
    └── pom.xml
```

Something close to the equivalent of doing:

```
git log -p workers
```

So basically I want to narrow the commits by directory.
And git does it **recursively**.
Regards.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

And use: `path:<dir>/**`

For example:

[image]

Which will list commits under `emacs` directory recursively.